# How to efficiently concatenate one set of lines with another set of lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

Say, I have 10 consecutive lines followed by another 10 lines, e.g.:

```
1
2
⋮
10
a
b
⋮
j
```

I want to append the lines from the second range (`a`…`j`) to the lines in the first range (`1`…`10`), so that the above 20 lines turn into the following 10 lines, instead:

```
1a
2b
⋮
10j
```

Which Vim commands can I use to achieve this?

Comment: See also the question about generalization of this problem: "[Vim paste -d ' ' behaviour out of the box?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9658612/254635)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my way:

```
qaG"aDdd9-$"apq
9@a
```

Explanation:

```
q             # Begin recording typed characters...
a             # to register 'a'
G             # Set cursor in last line.
"aD           # Delete the content from the beginning of line till the end and save it in register 'a'.
dd            # Previous command deleted the content but left the line in blank, delete the complete line.
9-            # Go back 9 lines.
$             # Set cursor at the end of current line (last number in your example).
"ap           # Paste content of register 'a' (at end of line without newline character).
q             # Stop recording.
---------------
9             # Run nine times.
@a            # Commands of register 'a' (all previous commmands).
```

- Register 'a' where I record commands is a different register of where I save content of each line, although they are named the same (letter 'a').

Answer (score 3):

I would start going to line with `a`, then <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>, `10j$d` to blockwise delete everything.

Then `:set virtualedit=all`, goto first line, move cursor right by 10 characters for example, and press p. Now remove first sequence of spaces in your ten lines.

There is a second way, which is basically the same:

- 10dd
- `:call setreg('"', @", '`**^V**`')` where **^V** is typed with CTRL-V CTRL-V
  (this will turn the register blockwise)
- P
- `:,+10s/ //g`

You can also do that programatically: enter Ex mode with Q, and type this

```
 let i = 1
 while i <= 10
    call setline(i, getline(i) . getline(11))
    11d
    let i = i + 1
 endwhile
 vi
```

If you intend to reuse it put this into your vimrc :

```
 function PasteLines(startline,numlines)
     let i = 0
     while i < a:numlines
        call setline(a:startline+i, getline(a:startline+i) . getline(a:startline+a:numlines))
        exec '' . (a:startline+a:numlines) . 'd'
        let i = i + 1
     endwhile
 endfunction
```

And call it with :

```
 :call PasteLines(1, 10)
```

where 1 is the first line, and 10 the number of lines. You need therefore 20 lines.

Comment: As one of your suggestions is to change the register type, I believe the UnconditionalPaste plugin by Ingo Karkat should be mentioned. As it does this with a rather nice mapping `gbP`. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355

Comment: What an over-engineering!  It is a job for [a short `:global` command or a macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752716/254635), both shorter than even call to `setreg()` or `PasteLines()`.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Assuming that the cursor is located on the first line of the
twenty-line block, let us consider the following short Ex command:

```
:,+9g/^/''+10m.|-j!
```

This is the `:global` command running on lines that belong to the
range of the next ten lines (starting from the current one). On every
of these lines, two Ex commands, `''+10m.` and `-j!`, are sequentially
executed. The first command takes the tenth line under the line at
which the cursor has been positioned and inserts it just below the
line where the cursor is currently located, using the `:move` command.
The `:join` command, `-j!`, appends the just moved line to the one
just above it (without inserting or deleting whitespace in between,
due to the `!` modifier).

There are two considerations that is necessary to take into account in
order to get the idea of that line movement. First, before the command
specified in a `:global` is executed on yet another line, the cursor
is positioned at the first column of that line. This way, the address
referenced in the aforementioned `:move` command as `.`, corresponds
to the latest line on which the command is currently being run.
Second, the number of the line that was the current one just before
a `:global` command was sent to execution, is added to the jump list.
Therefore, its address can be obtained in ranges through the
`'` pseudo-mark (see `:help :range`).

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9661121/254635) to the question “[Vim paste -d ' ' behaviour
out of the box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658612/vim-paste-d-behaviour-out-of-the-box)”.

**2.** The same effect can be achieved by means of Normal mode commands:

```
qqdd9+PgJ9-q9@q
```

This sequence of commands implements the same moving scheme, using a
macros to repeat a single-line transferring operation. The commands to
concatenate the first pair of lines, `dd9+PgJ9-`, are recorded in the
`"q` register using the `q` command. Similarly to the Ex command
proposed above, the macros deletes the current line (`dd`), moves the
cursor nine lines downward (`9+`), inserts the just cut line above the
new cursor position (`P`), joins that two lines without adding or
removing any spaces between them (`gJ`), and moves the cursor nine
lines upward (`9-`). Finally, these actions are automatically iterated
nine times using the `@` command to join the remaining nine pairs of
corresponding lines.

Comment: what does the `'` mark in a `:g` command do? (can you lead me to the relevant help section? It seems that I had sought for it but could not find).

Comment: @Benoit:  The `'` pseudo-mark has the same meaning here as everywhere else.  See the explanation above and `:help :range`, `:help ''`, `:help jumplist`.