# In vim, how do I paste a column of text to the end of irregular length lines?

Tags: vim

I would like to paste a column of text at the end of irregular-length lines.

For example, I would like to paste the following:

```
SRR447882.fastq.gz
SRR447883.fastq.gz
SRR447944.fastq.gz
```

at the end of these lines:

```
TIL01_
TIL01_
TIL04-TIP285_
```

Many times in the past, I simply create enough space on the first line that pasting will not come before the end of the existing text in the longest line. But then I need to go back and remove whitespace.

I have tried googling "vim column paste irregular length rows" and similar queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Start on the first line of the second block
- `qq`, start recording the `q` macro
- `4k`, go up four lines
- `d$`, delete till the end of line
- `4j`, go back to the previous line
- `$p`, paste the line at the end of the line
- `q`, stop recording the macro
- `jVG`, go down one line and select the remaining lines
- `:norm! @q`, apply the macro to the selection

It does however leave space where the previous text was. @Kent one's is still easier.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up using. Since it's just using macros, there's nothing extra for me to remember. I agree that Kent's solution looks nicer; but, for some reason `:right` seems to slow my vim interpreter down so much that it is unbearable. Your solution is the one that worked in my situation.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms another macro solution: `ddma2jpkJx'a`  cursor at the first `SRR..` line.

Answer (score 46):

You could try to do the following four steps:

1. block-wise select the first 3 lines (you want to paste later), and press `y`
2. line-wise select (`V`) the 3 lines ending with `_`, press `:right`
3. then move cursor to the end of the first line(`$`), paste the yanked text
4. `gv` re-select the lines, press `:left`

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice example of the `:right`, `block paste`, `:left` transform.

Comment: Oops, I did not see that the text to paste was not the same line repeated. Nice gif btw :)

Comment: @Zoneur Why don't you repost your answer? (with corrections, of course) You got me thinking about macros, which is what I ended up doing before I saw Kent's answer. I don't know what I didn't think of macros (I use them all the time). I guess I was too focused on cut/paste itself.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it does not solve your problem and I actually don't know how to do it using macros. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim) other answer though that merges two blocs, but is more complicated than Kent's solution.

Comment: @Zoneur A macro could copy from one block, move down to the corresponding line in the other block, paste at the end of the line, then return to the line just below the the starting point in the other block.

Comment: There are some good answers in the [Merge multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim) post. I personally like ib.'s answer: `:1,g/^/''+m.|-j!`. Which would solve this question as well although I believe the right/paste/left method is a bit easier to remember later.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Thanks, I managed to do it :) Restored my answer as you suggested.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms I thought there were variable lines between your two blocks of text. If the two blocks were continuous or there are fixed (relatively small) number of lines in between, it could be done by macro.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms please let me know if you are looking for a Macro only solution. I could post a macro answer.

Comment: @Kent +1. I really like your answer; don't change it. It's the one I'd use if vim didn't get really slow when I try using `:right`.

Comment: Cool demo, how did you record that?

Comment: is this answer so bad that it deserves a downvote? @downvoter, mind to leave a comment so that others can learn things?

Comment: If you have 1st piece of code various line length it's better to alight it right also so you could use line-wise selection. But later you will have a lot of extra spaces inside of lines. Could this be also solved?

Comment: @VladSavitsky perhaps you can post a new question with an example, it is a little bit hard to imagine what text do you have.

Answer (score 5):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has (among others) `gBp` / `gBP` mappings that paste register contents as a minimal fitting (not rectangular) block with a jagged right edge.

#### demo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Step 1` - goto to the start of the SPP... lines, then start Visual mode linewise with <kbd>V</kbd> (capital V), press <kbd>j</kbd> two times to get the desired lines selected then press <kbd>y</kbd>.

`Step 2` - goto the start of the TIL0... lines, then start Visual mode linewise with <kbd>V</kbd> (capital V), press <kbd>j</kbd> two times to get the desired lines selected then type...

```
:s;$;\=' ' . split(@")[line('.')-line("'<")];g`
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with a different feel to it:

`set ve=all` to permit insert/paste at arbitrary columns past eol.  Block-copy your source text, then at your first target line paste it with `100|P` (`100` being any column number longer than your target lines), then `:'[,']s, *\%100c,,`

If you do `p` instead of `P` you'll get a space separator.