# How to append a number sequence at the end of multiple lines with different length?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor

I'm rewriting some scripts. I would like to append to many lines like these:

```
short=s[
verylongword=s[
P=s[
```

These numbers:

```
0
1
2
```

To get this:

```
short=s[0
verylongword=s[1
P=s[2
```

I've tried with VIM ctrl+v put I can't put them at the end of the line... Which is the best way to do that even with emacs if with vim is not possible...

**EDIT:**
Now I know I can do it with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050070/in-vim-how-do-i-paste-a-column-of-text-to-the-end-of-irregular-length-lines?lq=1) if I have the number in a column like in my example, so the question is how can I append a number sequence faster without writing the squence first?

Comment: @G M: do you always want to add increasing numbers starting from 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In vim, how do I paste a column of text to the end of irregular length lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050070/in-vim-how-do-i-paste-a-column-of-text-to-the-end-of-irregular-length-lines)

Comment: G M: Can you respond to TacticalCoder's query? There's a disconnect between the title of your question and the answers you're getting, because your example uses an ascending sequence of numbers. Do you want answers for *arbitrary* lines of content, or just for a number sequence?

Comment: @phils in fact I just wanted to add multiple lines but because there are many answer to the other question I've change the question, do you think is the right thing to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, in the circumstances I think that's a good change -- it stops this from being a duplicate of the other question, without invalidating the answers you have in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vim you could use following search and replace statement

```
%s/$/\=line('.')-1
```

Breakdown

```
%                    apply to entire buffer
s                    substitute
/$                   search for end of line
/\=line('.')-1       replace with linenumber - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked vim or Emacs...

In Emacs you can simply select the lines to modify and then execute:

```
replace-regexp RET $ RET \# RET
```

(on a stock Emacs setup that would be `M-x replace-regexp...`)

The `\#` is a special substitution which starts at 0 and increments everytime a substitution is made. It is great and you can of course mix it with other elisp substitutions.

For example if you want to number your entries starting at 100:

```
replace-regexp RET $ RET \,(+ 100 \#) RET
```

Comment: I simply want a solution for my problem no matter how ,I can use both editor so if in emacs is more easy I can use it...

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs you can also use a keyboard macro to do this. With point at the end of the first line (`short=s[`), define it like this:

<kbd>F3</kbd> start macro definition

<kbd>F3</kbd> insert macro counter (starts at 0 by default)

<kbd>C-f</kbd> move to beginning of next line

<kbd>C-e</kbd> move to end of line

<kbd>F4</kbd> end macro definition

Execute the macro

- manually by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> repeatedly
- specifying a prefix argument representing the number of times (`n`) you would like to repeat the macro: <kbd>C-u</kbd> `n` <kbd>F4</kbd>
- specifying a prefix argument of `0` to repeat the macro for all remaining lines: <kbd>C-u</kbd> `n` <kbd>F4</kbd>

If you want the numbering to start at a value different than zero, set the macro counter value by issuing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kmacro-set-counter`. The default keybinding for this command is <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.