# Paste column after column

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-files, multiple-columns, code-formatting

I have a column of text like this:

```
usa
canada
alaska
```

And the second column:

```
,seattle
,toronto
,anchorage
```

I want add the second column next to the first like this

```
usa,seattle
canada,toronto
alaska,anchorage
```

I tried with the column mode, but the different lenghts made a mess.

Comment: There is a way to do it in vim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050070/in-vim-how-do-i-paste-a-column-of-text-to-the-end-of-irregular-length-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel like you have enough structure about your data to explain this better, but couldn't you just "find all" comma's to highlight all of the commas, press ctrl+shift+right until you highlight the second column values and then ctrl+left until the cursor is at the end of the first column values and paste them?

If you wanted to automate it and that's why you're asking for a regex, then you could just use find and replace like this:

```
     Find: ([a-zA-Z]*)([\t\ ]*)(\,([a-zA-z])*)
     Repl: $1$3
```

Use is find, any number of capital, or lower letters
as $1, followed by any number of tabs, or spaces as $2, 
and then a comma followed by any number of upper or lower 
case letters as $3.  You remove the spaces or tabs(replace
the second catch with any other delimiter or spacing if 
necessary

Edited to be copy&paste ready for you to use in Notepad++.
Don't forget to make sure "extended" is turned on in your
find/replace options so you can catch any tabs or spaces.

Result should be: Skip $2 in replace and return just row1,row3

Comment: *Remember regex is literal so you don't want any spaces in your statements or anything or the regex won't find because it'll be looking for the spaces, not the exact regex required.