# Using gvim, to copy few lines and paste them at the start of each line

Tags: vim, vi

Using `gvim`, I want to copy few lines and paste them at the start of each line.

**Eg:** I have the below lines in a file:

```
line1

line2

line3

and

line4

line5

line6
```

Now I want to copy and paste line1, line2 and line3 so that the file now looks as below:

```
line1 line4

line2 line5

line3 line5
```

I use visual block to copy line1, line2 and line3, but when I try to paste, I dont get the required result. 
Please could you help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim

Comment: That is strange, it should get you what you want. What do you get for a result?

Comment: @ryuichiro most likely the lines aren't the same length, so pasting the visual section starts overlapping them. So if line2 was longer then line1 you could end up with line5 in the middle of line2 like linline5e2

Comment: @FDinoff It didn't happen to me. The line 2 just pushed block 4, 5, 6, if I tried to prepend lines 1, 2, 3 with line 2 too long. Am I doing something wrong? For clarification, I am using P to prepend the block.

Comment: @ryuichiro Nevermind... Don't know then.